# Get elements heights using JS and pass into CSS variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables

I want to get the height of an element and pass it into a css variable. The issue im having is when i try to pass that number into the navHeight variable it ends up returning as undefined.

```
<script>
    let navHeightTest = document.getElementById("navbar").offsetHeight;
    console.log(navHeightTest); // Returns the nav height as a number
    
    let navHeight = Document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--nav-height', navHeightTest);
    console.log(`Nav Height=${navHeight}`); // Returns undefined 
</script>
```

CSS

```
    :root {
        --nav-height: 101px; /* Default Fallback Value */
    }
    .dynamic-margin {
        margin-top: calc(var(--nav-height) + 2.5rem) !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question - this can get confusing because `setProperty` returns `undefined`, not the value you just set.

Check out the **Return value** entry in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty#return_value

If you observe that the `--nav-height` variable isn't being updated either it might be because you're missing the units when you call `setProperty`. Since your default in the CSS is in pixels, and `offsetHeight` reports the number in pixels, I'm guessing you want pixels. Note the 'px' at the very end of the line.

```js
let navHeight = Document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--nav-height', navHeightTest + 'px');
```

Comment: thanks! i just tried figuring it out with chatGPT and it gave the same thing essentially - i was missing the "px". I did not know that setProperty returns undefined though, that is super helpful knowledge. Cheers!